# NgStyle returns: ERROR Error: Cannot find a differ supporting object '{"background-color":"blue"}'

Tags: angular, templates

With this in my template,

```
<span [ngStyle]="myStyle()"> HELLO </span>
```

And this in my component,

```
myStyle(): string {
  return '{"background-color":"blue"}'
}
```

I'm getting

```
ERROR Error: Cannot find a differ supporting object '{"background-color":"blue"}'
    at KeyValueDiffers.webpackJsonp.../../../core/@angular/core.es5.js.KeyValueDiffers.find (core.es5.js:8051)
    at NgStyle.set [as ngStyle] (common.es5.js:2441)
    at updateProp (core.es5.js:11114)
    at checkAndUpdateDirectiveInline (core.es5.js:10806)
    at checkAndUpdateNodeInline (core.es5.js:12349)
    at checkAndUpdateNode (core.es5.js:12288)
    at debugCheckAndUpdateNode (core.es5.js:13149)
    at debugCheckDirectivesFn (core.es5.js:13090)
    at Object.View_AppComponent_2.currVal_2 [as updateDirectives] (AppComponent.html:10)
    at Object.debugUpdateDirectives [as updateDirectives] (core.es5.js:13075)
View_AppComponent_2 @ AppComponent.html:10
webpackJsonp.../../../core/@angular/core.es5.js.DebugContext_.logError @ core.es5.js:13415
```

Answer (score 45, accepted):

The reason is that `[ngStyle]` does not accept a string. It accepts an object. Try this instead,

```
myStyle(): object {
  return {"background-color":"blue"};
}
```

Comment: This seems like a "typo" question. Why do you think it's useful as a self-answered question? Do you see this mistake often?

Comment: Typo or not, this is a mistake anyone can make.

Comment: @CodyGray I don't think it's a typo, but in a certain light I guess all mistakes are. I intended to pass a string. I was stupid. That's not what it expected. I didn't find the error intuitive at all. I hope it helps others.

Comment: I was missing square brackets around [ngStyle]. Still helped

Comment: @EvanCarroll How to achieve this if i want a filter style like -> {filter: blur(5px);}

Comment: @CodyGray it's now a famous question. Thanks for lettings it live.